# Пошаговое изменение значения при повторной анимации

Tags: анимация, ios

Здравствуйте! Можно ли при использовании анимации с опцией `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` изменять значение на каждой итерации анимации? 
Допустим, у меня есть вьюшка и она крутится 5 раз с помощью `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom` и я хочу менять `alpha` у вьюшки не за одну итерацию, а по немногу. Например при каждом шаге уменьшать на 0.2. 
Реально ли так сделать или нет?

```
 [UIView transitionWithView:view duration:0.5
 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom|                       UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                                animations:^{
                                    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:5.f];

                                }
                                completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Привет!
Попробуй вот это:

```
 view.alpha = 1.0;

 [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
             delay:0.0
             options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationAutoReverse
             animations:^{
                            view.alpha = 0.0;
                         }
             completion:nil
       ];
```

Comment: Конечно, это первое, что я попробовал. Но суть в том, что альфа снижается на каждой анимации повторно. То есть все пять шагов она снижается с 1 до 0. А нужно за пять шагов ОДИН раз снизить альфу до 0.